# Field of study and thesis

Tags: prepositions, expression-choice

Is there any proper way to say what field of study of an engineering thesis is?

In Polish I can say:

**Praca Dyplomowa Inżynierska na kierunku Informatyka**.

And it's often put on the front page as title.

Is there any English equivalent? Something like:

**Engineering Thesis (for/of?) Computer Science**.

Or perhaps

**Computer Science Engineering Thesis**.

Comment: You should conform to the customs of your department.  You should be able to access copies of recent theses in your department.  Is the Department secretary helpful -- you could ask him or her.  In my department and school (years ago) the custom was to put the exact title of one's thesis on the front page -- the title was descriptive of the subject of the thesis.

Comment: I don't think that my department expects me to apply some specific layout, but I'd like to use this one *unless* the construction in question is unheard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Your department may have very specific requirements for what the title page of your thesis says and how it looks.***  Ask a departmental secretary, your advisor, or another student.

What you propose does not give much information.  No one reading it will know whether they should read the thesis or not.

If your proposed format is OK with your department, "in" would be better then "for" or "of" in your first option, and your second option is better.

As an example, the title page of my MS thesis looked like this:

```
    ELECTRONIC STATES IN INSULATORS FOLLOWING K-CAPTURE 

                      OR INTERNAL CONVERSION

                               by

                            MY NAME

                      S.B., My University
                            (19NN)

       Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements

                 for the Degree of Master of Science

                           at the

                       MY UNIVERSITY

                       (Month, Year)



  Signature of Author .............................................
                            Department of Physics,  Month, Day, Year


 Certified by ....................................................
                                                 Thesis Supervisor

 Accepted by .....................................................
                                  Chairman, Departmental Committee
                                              on Graduate Students
```

And if I had varied *in the slightest respect* from this format, the Departmental Secretary would have, very kindly, told me what to correct and how to correct it.